# how to show my recent post on home?

Tags: ee2

please help me ... i'm nubiew on EE.

how to display the latest article on the front page, so I want each of my finished publishing my article and the article was immediately appear on the front page.

how to change this into a recent article:

```
<div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="span6">
                    <h3>Latest News</h3>
                    <ul class="bloglist-small">
                        <li>
                            <div class="date-box">
                                <span class="day">28</span>
                                <span class="month">SEP</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="txt">
                                <h5><a href="#">Lorem ipsum sit amet</a></h5>
                                <span class="read">Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem</span>
                                <span class="info">Sept 23, 2013 | <a href="#">Read More</a></span>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="date-box">
                                <span class="day">24</span>
                                <span class="month">SEP</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="txt">
                                <h5><a href="#">Lorem ipsum sit amet</a></h5>
                                <span class="read">Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem</span>
                                <span class="info">Sept 23, 2013 | <a href="#">Read More</a></span>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="date-box">
                                <span class="day">20</span>
                                <span class="month">SEP</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="txt">
                                <h5><a href="#">Lorem ipsum sit amet</a></h5>
                                <span class="read">Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem</span>
                                <span class="info">Sept 23, 2013 | <a href="#">Read More</a></span>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
```

this is screenshot:
[image: danchindia screenshot]

and this is my web  danchindia.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dan, i will advice you to take some time and learn the basic concept behind EE -:)
There are free tutorials around, on [Train-ee](http://www.train-ee.com/courseware/free-tutorials) for example you can follow the free tutorials. *[Building a Simple News Site from Start to Finish](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/how_to/building_a_simple_news_site.html)* is part of the official User Guide.

To show the 3 latest news, you can use this..

```
<ul>
{exp:channel:entries channel="news" limit="3"}
<li>
<div class="date-box">
<span class="day">{entry_date format="%d"}</span>
<span class="month">{entry_date format="%M"}<</span>
</div>

<div class="txt">
<h5><a href="{url_title_path='news'}">{title}</a></h5>
<span class="read">{YOUR_CUSTOM_FIELD}</span>
<span class="info">{entry_date format="%F %j, %Y"} | <a href="{url_title_path='news'}">Read More</a></span>
</div>
</li>                                               
{/exp:channel:entries}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to create a snippet called {sp_lastest_post} and place these lines inside it

```
<ul class="bloglist-small">
    {exp:channel:entries channel="channel_name"
                         category="cat_id"
                         limit="10"}

        {!-- Begin Loop --}
        {!-- Replace below values with channel entries tag variables --}
        <li>
            <div class="date-box">
                <span class="day">28</span>
                <span class="month">SEP</span>
            </div>
            <div class="txt">
                <h5><a href="#">Lorem ipsum sit amet</a></h5>
                <span class="read">Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem</span>
                <span class="info">Sept 23, 2013 | <a href="#">Read More</a></span>
            </div>
        </li>

        {!-- No Results Message --}
        {if no_results}<h4>Updating...</h4>{/if}


    {/exp:channel:entries}
</ul>
```

Then place the snippet to wherever you want your posts to appear.

Comment: I'm glad it helps! Cheers!